# MS-Word Wildcard Search/Replace in VBA/Macro-Enabled Doc Change in Behavior (@ wildcard not working)

Tags: regex, vba, replace, ms-word, wildcard

Here’s a bizarre one.  I have been using for years a macro-enabled document that basically “cleans-up” my notes using the MS Word Search & Replace and wildcards.

Yesterday, the behavior changed drastically and it no longer works as expected.  Still evaluating all of the issues, but the following search immediately caused concern:

```
Search string: (<[A-Za-z'’]@)[ ,.;:]@\1>
Replace string: \1
Purpose: Removes duplicate words
Sample text: test test
Result: Search highlights “test test” fully; 
executing replace returns “test” (expected)
```

This has worked perfectly, so much so that I have automated it with a macro, below, which is saved in a macro-enabled template (dotm) that I open to create a new document each time for my notes:

```
Sub FindReplaceRepeatWords()
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "(<[A-Za-z']@)[ ,.;:]@\1>"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
End Sub
```

On or about yesterday, the macro-enabled document now performs the following, whether manually run or via VBA:

```
Sample text: test test
Result: Search highlights “t” (first “t” in “test test” only); 
executing replace returns “t” (incorrect; ignoring the function of the "@" wildcard)
```

Importantly, manually running the search & replace with wildcards in a new docx (normal.dot) still works as expected.   My original dotm no longer does, and if I create a brand new dotm template with no macros whatsoever, save it, and then try to run the wildcard search again manually, it also fails finding only the first character.

I have a bunch of other macros in the document that I need for my “clean-up” work, so simply running the duplicate word search manually in a standard docx isn’t an option.   Also, it appears there’s an issue with another macro that searches for the character “@” versus the wildcard to change it, and it's not working as expected (still diagnosing that one).

It’s as if there is a problem using the “@” character in a macro-enabled document now for some reason.   As the new test dotm template had no VBA code, and I have high confidence in what I’ve coded and have used it for years, I don’t think it’s the VBA code itself.

What’s changed?  Harder to tell now-a-days, but suspiciously Office had just updated to: Version 2302 (Build 16130.20218).

Thinking there must be something buggy/different in that update, I rolled back to: Version 2301 (Build 16026.20146).  No change.
Windows is 21H2 Build 190.44.2486.

Not sure where to go from here to troubleshoot.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

edit: formatting

Comment: Never saw this functionality in Word before! Thanks for sharing it. It's a bit of a shame that Word has its own syntax, which is different from common regular expression engines. But at least there is one! I know it won't help you a lot, but your example is working fine on my Mac OS X Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68) with Microsoft Word 16.70 (23021201).

Comment: Interestingly, the spell check finds the duplicated words, but does not suggest anything remotely related.   e.g. "okay okay" returns "Not in dictionary: 'and like'  No suggestions."   Another, for "and and."  "Not in dictionary: So.  No suggestions."  It used to say it was a duplicated word and suggest deleting the second; now it flags the second word (e.g. okay) and claims it found something entirely different (and like), which is not even misspelled, so no suggestions.